# Implementação HttpURLConnection muito lenta ao executar

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Estou utilizando a classe `HttpURLConnection` para realizar a conexão com um site que retorna um JSON e fiz a seguinte codificação:

```
URL url = new URL("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/rest/controller/get.json");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

Ao executar os métodos `url.openConnection()` e `connection.connect()` o sistema demora muito para responder. Eu até tenho o retorno desejado, mas chega a demorar uns 5 minutos para executar os métodos.
Por que isso está ocorrendo? Lembrando que estou fazendo tudo dentro do método `doInBackground` de uma `AsyncTask`

Comment: Mostra sua AsyncTask. Alguma outra rotina pode estar lenta, não o ato da conexão. (debugou?)